# Sum (Hours, minutes and seconds) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I built a query that performs a calculation to get the time between checkin and checkout. The date/time is recorded in the same field, whether at checkin or checkout. Soon, I had to do a `LEAD` and `PARTITION BY` to be able to separate, until then it's solved. I can separately get the difference in hours, minutes and seconds, but I wouldn't want it to be that way, but all together.

Below the query:

```
WITH T_REPRES
AS (
    SELECT USU.CODIGO_ACESSO
        ,USU.USUARIO
        ,USU.CODIGO
    FROM DB_USUARIO USU
        --WHERE USU.NIVEL_REPRESENTANTE IN (@IDESTRUTURA)
    )
SELECT T2.USUARIO
    ,T2.DATA AS PERIODO
    ,T2.FUNCIONALIDADE
    ,T2.DATA_CHECKOUT
    ,CONCAT((DATEDIFF(HOUR, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT, T2.DATA) / 24) * -1
        ,':'
        ,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT, T2.DATA) % 60) * -1
        ,':'
        ,(DATEDIFF(SECOND, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT, T2.DATA) % 60) * -1
    ) AS CONCATEADO
FROM (
    SELECT T1.USUARIO
        ,T1.DATA
        ,T1.FUNCIONALIDADE
        ,LEAD(T1.DATA) OVER (
            PARTITION BY T1.USUARIO
            ,CAST(T1.DATA AS DATE) ORDER BY T1.USUARIO
                ,T1.DATA
                ,T1.FUNCIONALIDADE
            ) DATA_CHECKOUT
    FROM (
        SELECT REP.USUARIO
            ,TE.DATA
            ,TE.FUNCIONALIDADE
            ,TE.CODIGO_CLIENTE
        FROM DB_MOB_TIMELINE_EVENTOS TE
            ,T_REPRES REP
        WHERE TE.FUNCIONALIDADE IN (
                'CHECKIN'
                ,'CHECKOUT'
                )
            AND TE.USUARIO = REP.USUARIO
        ) T1
    ) T2
WHERE T2.DATA_CHECKOUT IS NOT NULL
    AND CAST(T2.DATA AS DATE) = '2023-04-17'
```

The result is below:

[image: Example:]

I would like to have a result adding all this concatenated return, example: 00:35:54. All hours, minutes and seconds. If you give more than 60 seconds, count another minute. If you give more than 60 minutes, count an hour.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Does it make sense to add all these up? If this is a reciprocal 2 event system, then we could take the earliest time and subtract that from the latest time. Normally we would count the `CHECKIN` and `CHECKOUT` status separatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those issues where generally you would format the results within the presentation layer (UI or Reporting) or the service layer of your application and *not* the data access.

- This is simply because the presentation layers are optimized to perform this type of manipulation.

What you have done with the `CONCAT` is almost correct if you need to see the time in that format, you are noticing a rounding error, or actually it is a *trim* error. We fix this by only using the **least significant interval**, in this case *seconds*. We can reverse the times to make things a bit easier to read, add some formatting and can further reduce the calculations using `APPLY`.

```
,CONCAT(
     FORMAT((Tx.[Seconds]/3600) % 24,'00')
    ,':'
    ,FORMAT((Tx.[Seconds]/60) % 60,'00')
    ,':'
    ,FORMAT(Tx.[Seconds] % 60,'00')
) AS CONCATEADO
FROM (...) T2
OUTER APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, T2.DATA, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT) as [Seconds]) as Tx
```

> I am using `OUTER APPLY` here as an efficiency, technically `CROSS APPLY` will do but this result is 1:1 so I am happy to avoid the validation checks that come with `CROSS`...

https://dbfiddle.uk/lm4P6uE8

| USUARIO | PERIODO | FUNCIONALIDADE | DATA_CHECKOUT | Old_CONCATEADO | TotalSeconds | CONCATEADO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 09:56:29.0000000 | CHECKIN | 2023-04-17 10:19:09.0000000 | 0:23:40 | 1360 | 00:22:40 |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 10:19:09.0000000 | CHECKOUT | 2023-04-17 10:22:36.0000000 | 0:3:27 | 207 | 00:03:27 |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 10:22:36.0000000 | CHECKIN | 2023-04-17 10:23:25.0000000 | 0:1:49 | 49 | 00:00:49 |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 10:23:25.0000000 | CHECKOUT | 2023-04-17 10:23:50.0000000 | 0:0:25 | 25 | 00:00:25 |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 10:23:50.0000000 | CHECKIN | 2023-04-17 10:25:02.0000000 | 0:2:12 | 72 | 00:01:12 |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 10:25:02.0000000 | CHECKOUT | 2023-04-17 10:25:04.0000000 | 0:0:2 | 2 | 00:00:02 |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 10:25:04.0000000 | CHECKIN | 2023-04-17 10:26:59.0000000 | 0:1:55 | 115 | 00:01:55 |
| P126211 | 2023-04-17 10:26:59.0000000 | CHECKOUT | 2023-04-17 10:27:01.0000000 | 0:1:2 | 2 | 00:00:02 |

You do not have to use the *same* calculation as I have here, but due to the trimming that occurs in `DATEDIFF` to get accurate values you need to use at least 1 interval lower than the value that you want to calculate.

We can also cheat by using `DATEADD` to add our seconds to zero and format the time portion: https://dbfiddle.uk/_QaNLBRG

```
,FORMAT(DATEADD(s, Tx.[Seconds], 0), 'HH:mm:ss') AS CONCATEADO
```

But if we do that, then we don't really need the `APPLY` anymore!

```
WITH T_REPRES
AS (
    SELECT USU.CODIGO_ACESSO
        ,USU.USUARIO
        ,USU.CODIGO
    FROM DB_USUARIO USU
        --WHERE USU.NIVEL_REPRESENTANTE IN (@IDESTRUTURA)
    )
SELECT T2.USUARIO
    ,T2.DATA AS PERIODO
    ,T2.FUNCIONALIDADE
    ,T2.DATA_CHECKOUT
    ,FORMAT(DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(SECOND, T2.DATA, T2.DATA_CHECKOUT), 0), 'HH:mm:ss') AS CONCATEADO
FROM (
    SELECT T1.USUARIO
        ,T1.DATA
        ,T1.FUNCIONALIDADE
        ,LEAD(T1.DATA) OVER (
            PARTITION BY T1.USUARIO
            ,CAST(T1.DATA AS DATE) ORDER BY T1.USUARIO
                ,T1.DATA
                ,T1.FUNCIONALIDADE
            ) DATA_CHECKOUT
    FROM (
        SELECT REP.USUARIO
            ,TE.DATA
            ,TE.FUNCIONALIDADE
            ,TE.CODIGO_CLIENTE
        FROM DB_MOB_TIMELINE_EVENTOS TE
            ,T_REPRES REP
        WHERE TE.FUNCIONALIDADE IN (
                'CHECKIN'
                ,'CHECKOUT'
                )
            AND TE.USUARIO = REP.USUARIO
        ) T1
    ) T2
WHERE T2.DATA_CHECKOUT IS NOT NULL
    AND CAST(T2.DATA AS DATE) = '2023-04-17'
```

> You will have to evaluate these techniques in your environment depending on your indexing, schema and database version, a variation of the `CROSS APPLY` solution may be more efficient than `FORMAT`.

To get the totals, we simply `SUM` the seconds and then use the same format technique. In this example I'll use a *window query* instead of another inline table expression but you should be able to adjust this without too much effort: https://dbfiddle.uk/p4RvT90X

Seconds:

```
,SUM(Tx.[Seconds]) OVER (PARTITION BY USUARIO) as TotalSeconds
,SUM(CASE WHEN FUNCIONALIDADE = 'CHECKIN' THEN Tx.[Seconds] END) OVER (PARTITION BY USUARIO) as TotalCheckInSeconds
,SUM(CASE WHEN FUNCIONALIDADE = 'CHECKOUT' THEN Tx.[Seconds] END) OVER (PARTITION BY USUARIO) as TotalCheckOutSeconds
```

Formatted by substituting in those expressions:

```
,FORMAT(DATEADD(s, SUM(Tx.[Seconds]) OVER (PARTITION BY USUARIO), 0), 'HH:mm:ss') AS Total 
,FORMAT(DATEADD(s, SUM(CASE WHEN FUNCIONALIDADE = 'CHECKIN' THEN Tx.[Seconds] END) OVER (PARTITION BY USUARIO), 0), 'HH:mm:ss') AS CheckIn 
,FORMAT(DATEADD(s, SUM(CASE WHEN FUNCIONALIDADE = 'CHECKOUT' THEN Tx.[Seconds] END) OVER (PARTITION BY USUARIO), 0), 'HH:mm:ss') AS CheckOut
```

| TotalSeconds | TotalCheckInSeconds | TotalCheckOutSeconds | Total | CheckIn | CheckOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1832 | 1596 | 236 | 00:30:32 | 00:26:36 | 00:03:56 |

Comment: Initially I misinterpreted OP thinking that they wanted to know why their numbers were wrong, so we get two answers for the one question in this case ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Time1.1, Time2.1)))/3600), 'hr ',
        FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Time1.2, Time2.2))%3600)/60), 'min ',
        FLOOR((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Time1.3, Time2.3))%60)), 'sec'
    ) AS 'time_elapsed'
FROM 
    my_table
```

You can replace 'Time 1.1' with the time in question

Comment: Hi, bro.
The TIME_TO_SEC and TIMEDIFF functions are for MySQL. I need for T-SQL.

Comment: @LucasSilveira [DATEDIFF function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).